Deploying the tabular cube failed with a timerunot error
I'm encountering an issue while deploying the cube. It's failing, as shown in the image below. Can anyone help me with this? I have 80 Millions of rows  :

Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The XML
for Analysis request timed out before it was completed. Timeout value:
300 sec. The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was
completed. Timeout value: 300 sec.


While deploying the tabular cube into the analysis server
